# How to handle shopping cart system when not login and after login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a shopping cart system, but I am quite confused with how to build it properly when it comes to this two situation,

1. When User is not logged in
2. When User login

So in first situation I can use local storage to manage the data, and the second, I can use database to store the user's shopping cart , but here come the problem ,

1. if User add something when not log in , but he already has different items in their database shopping cart , I can just add them together or replace the local storage shopping cart with database one ?
2. As I said if I use two different strategy , before each shopping cart related function, I should add "if user is login " to decide it would send by API or just store the data in local storage , is it really a proper approach ?
3. If above is not the good approach , then how should I structure my project ?

I am not really familiar with real world web design , and I watch a few shopping cart tutorial , I don't think they cover enough ground for real production , maybe someone can provide a good real production example using React + NodeJS , I would be much appreciate !!

Comment: Another solution would be to also give each anonymous user a session and handle all users the same. This is a bit more stress on the server, but easier to code and maintain. But nothing against your solution, as long as it works correctly. Why not check some open source shopping systems and check how they handle it?

Comment: @PeterKrebs Do you know some good react shopping systems examples? and can you pass the link?  thanks!

Comment: I have not encountered react shopping systems yet, no. But [Magento (Headless)](https://magento.com/products/magento-commerce/headless-commerce) can be used to create any frontend you wish, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a business decision. Get your product people and your UX people involved.

If you don't have those, there are multiple things you could do.

1. Add a date of creation to your shopping carts. You can then experiment with either prioritizing the latest one, or asking the user to choose between their last two
2. Merge them into one. This is very likely not what the user wants, especially if their older cart is older than, say, 24 hours.
3. Speaking of which, shopping carts should expire. Most ecommerce platforms I've worked with usually archive the shopping carts after some time (15-60 mins). During this time they keep the items in the cart as reserved so no two people end up competing for the same stock.
4. Expired carts can be stored so you can send an email to your user with a link that allows them to get back to their unfinished purchase.

So with that in mind, consider the following questions:

- How relevant is each shopping cart to the user? Do you have a way of chosing the "most" relevant one?
- Are you dealing with physical goods where you need to keep track of the stock? Then you probably need to "reserve" the appropriate amount of items for each cart, and you'd need to "expire" each cart
- Do you ever want to present your users with a choice of two shopping carts? If yes, create an interface where they can do that. If no, consider prioritizing the latest cart and consider sending an email to the user reminding them about the earlier.

Your problem is with having too many options, not with having no choice, so you need to either get your peers involved, or start A/B testing. I think you'll only get subjective answers here.

Comment: That's what I thought, I have too many options to choose one, But I have more clear thoughts after your explanation, thanks!